# use object in CgridView for value

Tags: php, date, widget, yii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Yii gridview use outside variable in value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594164/yii-gridview-use-outside-variable-in-value)

I develop following code in Yii,I know I can use pure php or static method for value of CGridView,but now I wanna use a method of object for value. but it can't find `$data` variable. how can I solve it?

```
<?php
Yii::import('application.dlib.*');
$jdate = new jCalendar();
$jdate->farsiDigits = false;
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'enterlog-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'driverid',
    array(
                'name'=>'time',
                'value'=> $jdate->date("Y",$data->time)
             ),
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

the following error occurred when I run above code:
`Undefined variable: data` 
and when I do

```
'value'=> '$jdate->date("Y",$data->time)'
```

the following error `Undefined variable: jdate`

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: have you tried anonymous function : [like in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11594298/720508)

Comment: @bool.dev: The documentation is almost criminally negligent in not mentioning that you can pass in any callable for `value` -- although strings are going to be `eval`'ed instead of treated as function names.

Comment: @Jon agreed :) , and the documentation lacks in a lot of other places too!