# How to display value from the array in yii list view

Tags: php, listview, yii

I am new to yii and displaying the user information in the yii list view , problem is i have a country list and on that base I have a country code to display the country but i want to show the country value not country code , i have an array like this

```
array('IN'=>'India','US'=>'United State'............................,'AUS'=>'Australia');
```

i am using this code in the view to display information

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'site_id',
        'name',
        'desc',
        'status',
        's_icon',
        array(
            'name' => 'sys_country',
            'value' =>$sysinfo->sys_country,
        ),

    ),
)); ?>
```

it is displaying the country code, is there any way so that i can pass the country array and from this array i can found the value from the array key

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii gridview use outside variable in value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594164/yii-gridview-use-outside-variable-in-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do it this way:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'site_id',
    'name',
    'desc',
    'status',
    's_icon',
    array(
        'name' => 'sys_country',
        'value' =>$countryArray[$model->sys_country],
    ),

),));
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have `tbl_country` table:

```
country_code | country_name
------------ | ------------
IN           | India
US           | United States
...          | ...
```

and you have `Country` model for that table.

Then you can define a `country` relation for `User`model:

```
public function relations () {
    return array(
        'country' => array( self::BELONGS_TO, 'Country', 'country_code' ),
    );
}
```

Now in `CDetailView` you can simply use `country.country_name`:

```
'attributes'=>array(
    ...
    'name',
    'status',
    'country.country_name',
    ...
),
```